# Removing iMesh from Internet Explorer

Tags: internet, windows-explorer, uninstall, imesh

A while back I installed iMesh but then uninstalled it by going to Computer > Unistall or Change a Programme

But even now, when I open a new tab it takes me to the imesh search bar, and when typing a search into the browser bar, it searches it with imesh

How do I uninstall it completely from my computer and internet explorer?

Comment: Manage Add-Ons menu is also available in IE6 under Tools\Program Tab.

Answer (score 1):

It's annoying but simple -  the Imesh add-on is not part of the program itself, and needs to be uninstalled seperately from the downloading program itself. I don't recall exactly what the add-on is called but look through your list - if it's still there I assure you you will find another program called imesh.

Comment: That worked thanks. I went into mangae add ons and disabled
Name UrlHelper Class
Publisher iMesh, Inc.
Status Disabled
File date Wednesday, 10 August 2011, 12:35 a.m.
Version 3.0.0.46593
Load time (0.00 s) Yay!

Answer (score 0):

The user-friendly way will be [running free anti-spyware software](http://www.ehow.com/how_6642517_remove-imesh-spyware.html), though it requires installation and a multi-hour scan that may or may not find your problem.

Manually, you might want to see if your homepage was redirected under `Tools \ internet options \ General Tab`.

If you have anything newer than IE6, then you can probably delete it via `Tools \ Manage Add-Ons`. On the left, look inside `Toolbars and Extensions` and also in `Search Providers`, and from the lists on the right, select the offending iMesh parts and click on Remove.

Welcome, and good luck. You can comment under here if you need more assistance.